# Creating Alert Dialog and Making Notification Gives the Error: Unable to Add Window

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, android-alertdialog

I'd first like to state that this is not a duplicate of the "Unable to Add Window" error problem that others were receiving with Alert Dialogs. What this app does is create a notification and Alert Dialog when a value is added to a certain path in Firebase. I tested the notification and Alert Dialog **individually and they were working**. Even when the app was in the background, I didn't get any errors.

The problem "Unable to Add Window" came when I tried tapping on the notification to take me back to my app. The way that my app functions is that on another device, a button is pressed and it inserts some values into Firebase under two paths, one for notifications, and another for the Alert Dialog. Then, on my current device, it reads from those paths to check if they are not empty. If they aren't empty, then it will create a notification and the Alert Dialog.

**Current behavior:** What is happening right now, is that the notification and Alert Dialog appear in the activity. The notification also pops up when I am in another app as long as my app is in the background. **The problem comes when I press on the notification to take me back to my app. It does take me to the activity, as expected, but when the new values are inserted into Firebase, it gives me the "Unable to Add Window" error.**

I am unable to figure out why this error is occurring because the Alert Dialog and notification work fine in the app, but when I use the notification to go to the app, I get this error. *I have tried reading other StackOverflow answers for the same "Unable to add Window" error, but none of those solutions have worked for me because they had to do with the context of the Alert Dialog, whereas here my problem is with the notification taking me back to my app.*

This is the [link to my full Java code](https://github.com/ishaanjav/CaretakerDevice/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/anany/caretakerdevice/CaretakerAccount.java) on GitHub.
Here is the function which I call to create a notification:

```
private void makeNotification(DatabaseReference databaseReference102, String value) {
// The error occurs when I click on the notification to take me back to the app which is in the code below.
//When I click on the notification, the next time values are aded to Firebase, it gives me the "Unable to Add Window" error.
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaretakerAccount.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("A User Logged In!")
            .setContentText(value + " just logged in!")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(value + " just logged in!"))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    databaseReference102.removeValue();
   //Removes the value in the notification path that way the notification is not made repeatedly.
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could rather add some useful and small amount of code in which you think problem might be, it'd be helpful.

Comment: I think the problem is with clicking on the notification to go to the app. This is on lines 212- 235 at the [link over here](https://github.com/ishaanjav/CaretakerDevice/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/anany/caretakerdevice/CaretakerAccount.java#L231)

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Ok. I added the function which is used to make the notification which is probably where the problem occurs.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit do you have any ideas for why I am getting this error. At this point, I am very certain that the error is with the notification, but I am not able to figure out why when I press it, it is not able to create the Alert Dialog.

Comment: Since the notification is shown, I do not believe that the problem is in the code you added (which simply shows that you create the notification).

Comment: In that case, what may be the problem? When I use the notification to go back to my app, it works as expected: I am able to go to other activities and do other things. However, when those values are added to Firebase, I get that error of "Unable to Add Window" even though when I was outside the app I never got that problem. Thanks for the feedback.